# Where can I view connection string used for dataset in Power BI only having .pbix with no access to data source?

Tags: powerbi, connection-string

I had to reformat a report and need to verify the connection string is pointing to a particular database. I DON'T have access to the database in which the data set was pulled from and was only given the .pbix to reformat the report. However, I was asked to verify that this dataset was pulled from this particular database mentioned hence needing to check the endpoint included in the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Query Editor and look at the Source statement of the query. In some cases, there is also a Navigate statement after the Source statement, e.g. Source points to a SQL Server database, Navigate goes to a specific table or view.

The first two or three lines of the code in the Advanced Editor will give you the whole picture.